# Given that $\sum b(n)$ is convergent, is $\sum a(n)$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider

- $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} b(n)$, such that for all $n$, $0<b(n) ≤1$
- $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} a(n)$ such that for all $n$, $-b(n)≤a(n)≤b(n)$.

Given that $\sum b(n)$ is convergent, is $\sum a(n)$ convergent? Prove it in detail.

Comment: If $b$'s are always possitive, then the $b$ series is absolutely convergent, so the $a$ series is also (absolutely) convergent.

Comment: You shuld write $a_n,b_n$ throughout, not $a,b.$

Comment: The first requirement can be relaxed to $b(n)\ge 0.$

Comment: When you say "Prove it in detail", it makes me think it means "Do my homework for me".

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n) \leq \bigg|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)\bigg|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a(n)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty b(n) < \infty
$$

The third inequality follows from $-b\leq a \leq b \iff |a|\leq b$.

Being a bit more pedantic - we use the fact that absolute convergence implies convergence. In other words, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a(n)|$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ converges. The former converges because every element of the series is bounded by the corresponding $b(n)$. (Being ever more pedantic, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a(n)|$ converges because the truncated series is a bounded and increasing monotone sequence, thus it converges.)

Comment: That's not really a correct proof. $\sum a_n$ has no meaning until you prove it converges, which is the point of the problem. Your comment is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The second condition implies $|a(n)|\le b(n)$ for every $n.$  Since $\sum b(n) < \infty,$ $\sum |a(n)|<\infty$ by the comparison test. Thus $\sum a(n)$ converges absolutely, hence converges.

Answer (score -1):

If $\sum a_n$ be diverge, then $\lim a_n=\ell\neq0$ then
$$0<\ell=\lim |a_n|≤\lim b_n$$

Comment: Your downvote shows my answer is wrong or shows my attempt was unfruitful.